# Different Behavior between Numeric Literals and Constrained Function Parameters in Haskell

Tags: haskell, type-families

I've been trying to figure out the more finnicky bits of Haskell's type system by writing a Vector library. Ideally, I'd like an overloaded vector multiplication operation that works a bit like C++, i.e, you can multiply a vector of any size by a scalar, in either order.
I've tried to combine the multiple parameter type classes and type families extension to do this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, MultiParamTypeClasses, FlexibleInstances #-}

data Vec2 a = Vec2 (a,a) deriving (Show, Eq, Read)

class Vector a where
    (<+>) :: a -> a -> a

class VectorMul a b where
    type Result a b
    (<*>) :: a -> b -> Result a b

instance (Num a) => Vector (Vec2 a) where
    Vec2 (x1,y1) <+> Vec2 (x2,y2) = Vec2 (x1+x2, y1+y2)

instance (Num a) => VectorMul (Vec2 a) a where
    type Result (Vec2 a) a = (Vec2 a)
    Vec2 (x,y) <*> a = Vec2 (x*a, y*a)

works :: (Num a) => Vec2 a -> a -> Vec2 a
works a b = a <*> b
```

This code seems to work, at least when used as in the function `works`. But when I try to type a simple expression like `Vec2 (3,4) <*> 5` into GHCi, it reports the `(Num xx)` type variables to be ambiguous. This is strange to me... what am I missing in this case? Haskell should be able to choose the same arbitrary type for the literals, to make the type expression work (as it does in the `works` function).

Comment: In `works` you are explicitly saying `a` in `Vec2 a` and the second argument `a` has the same type.

Comment: This question is really about [type defaulting](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/decls.html#sect4.3.4), and why it doesn't kick in here as you seem to expect.

Answer (score 1):

Try to write

```
Vec2 (3,4 :: Int) <*> (5 :: Int)
```

In `Vec2 (3,4) <*> 5` it is not guarantee that `3,4 ::Num a` and `5 :: Num b` have the same `a` and `b`